# Java, read contents of file from search

Tags: java

I'd like to be able to optomize my code:

```
} else if (s.equals("2")) {
    System.out.println("Please enter a Name, Phone Number or Email Address: ");
    dataLine = in.readLine();
    String result = readFromFile("C:/AddressBook.dat", dataLine);
    System.out.println("Search Results\n" + result);
```

When a user types in a name/phone number/email it will search through the AddressBook.dat file for the entry matching that search result and come back with the completed entry for that search.
So far it only comes back with exactly what was searched.
e.g. search name Jack will come back with just Jack.

I hope this is clear enough and I'm very sorry if this question may have already been answered, I've tried looking for the answer already.

It would probably help if I uploaded my entire code...
http://pastebin.com/5LY68J5U

Sorry about that!

Comment: show what you already implemented in `readFromFile`

Comment: show the file format.

Comment: You're posting the wrong part of the code :)

Comment: Post the code of readfromFile

Comment: Added full code, sorry!

Comment: What is the error you are facing ?

Answer (score 2):

From the method name and params, I assume you are reading the file from disk. Don't open the file at each query, keep it somewhere in memory if it is small. Otherwise, try storing data in a sqlite database file, which is optimized for queries (being engineered for this task).

EDIT: the code you posted confirms my assumption. Read the file once and keep it in memory as stated above. File opening and reading from disk is much slower than memory access.

Comment: Well, it's more than a guess. Fixed, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using my mobile to answer this, so the site is blocking the answer due to some chars in it,so please check what I'm trying to say 
http://pastebin.com/Ez7cSJGJ
Hope I helped :)